# Webform select option list from another submission data

Tags: webforms

I have a webform (webform 1) to record data. In another webform (webform 2) I would like to use the submitted data from webform 1 in select options (Load a pre-built option list). How can I do this? Is there any module that already available to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the sandbox project [Webform Views Select](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mrconnerton/1373760).

Comment: This module is what I am looking for. From the information it can apply the filter of submitted webform data to appear in another webform select list. However, I have to learn more to use this since I have blank select list. Another alternative module I found is Webform Submission Reference (https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_submissionref). I can get the select list easier, but the submitted result is a link (for example, Submission #30), instead of value as appear in the form, reported here https://www.drupal.org/node/2482465 .

Comment: A patch https://www.drupal.org/node/2483637 to solve the problem of not rendered values from webform submission data is recently available. Indeed the Webform Views Select (https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mrconnerton/1373760) is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The [Webform Autocomplete](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_autocomplete) can do something *similar* to your requirement: it can allow users to autocomplete answers that were already given for that field on the webform. So if one user types "Manhattan" into a field and submits the form, the next person who uses that webform can start typing "ma", and "Manhattan" (and all other previous answers starting with "ma") will be selectable.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The module (https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_autocomplete) however populates from the previous submissions using the same webform in the same field. I need to use submitted data from different webform, available in the select option list.