# Want a select option of a field saved in another form

Tags: webforms

i have a web form having following fields for sales department:
client name(text field), quarter(select option), countries(select option), Annual fees(number), Monthly fees(number), setup(fees)......

now i want to create a form in which i can have a list of all the client saved by above form
 for management to allot resources for the client

please suggest any module required or coding which required.

need help urgently on this

Answer (score 0):

The module is [Webform Views Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_views_select).

This question is related to this question.

[Webform select option list from another submission data](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/157051)